# How to make push and pop on queue atomic, how to lock those operations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, stl, queue

I am using queue for communication between two threads ( one just producing instance of custom class and pushes pointer to queue, other read from queue pointer on custom class and make some calculations). How to make push and pop on queue atomic, how to lock those operations ?( I cannot use C++11 standard )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the most portable non-C++11 locking mechanism is are the [synchronisztion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html) types from the [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread.html) library. In particular the [mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex) class gives you a simple lockable object for giving exclusive access to a resource. For example:

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <queue>

template <typename T>
class locking_queue {
public:
    void push(T const & value) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        queue.push(value);
    }

    bool pop(T & value) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        if (queue.empty()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            value = queue.front();
            queue.pop();
            return true;
        }
    }

private:
    std::queue<T> queue;
    boost::mutex mutex;
};
```

Another advantage is that this is quite similar to the C++11 `std::mutex` class, which will make conversion quite straightforward if you decide to use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pseudo code:

```
// Thread A
mutex.lock();
q.push();
mutex.unlock();

// Thread B
mutex.lock();
q.pop();
mutex.unlock();
```

If you're using boost, you may try it's [mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/mutex.html) class.

Comment: Although you should always use a RAII-style scoped lock, so the mutex doesn't remain locked for ever if `push` or `pop` throws an exception.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - meh, who cares?  If an op as simple as push/pop from a queue can throw an exception, the app is in deep brown stuff anyway :(